# What is the `bump` in a Program Derived Address?

Tags: pda, metaplex-js

So program derived addresses `import { Pda } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";` seem to be Solana addresses  like any other, except they have a `bump` associated with them - I can see then when writing unit tests and wanting to compare one `Pda` with an expected `Pda`.

What is the `bump`?

```
new Pda("2TQ464nFCwPs45wYsXXYpkhY7wgUyEVzpecWp1RBMeDU", 255),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I will refer to Solana web3.js but there is no difference with the metaplex SDK about the concept of PDAs.*

A PDA corresponds to 1 address **+ 1 bump**. You can have different bumps for a given address. Imagine, you have an address AbCdEf. Bumps provide variations to this address. For example:

- AbCd, 255
- AbCd, 253
- etc...

Note that bump 255 does not always exist, nor does the next bump has to be 254 or 253. That's why you need to run a function called [findProgramAddress](https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#generate-a-pda) to *"find"* the PDA, and this function goes like this:

```
function findProgramAddress(...) {
  let bump = 255

  while (bump != 0) {
    const address = tryCreateProgramAddressWithBump(..., bump)

    if (isValidPDA(address) {
      // We found the valid combination of address + bump
      // -> This is a valid pda 
      return [address, bump]
    } else {
      // that's not a valid combination 
      // let's try again with next bump 254, then 253, etc.
      bump--
    }
  }
}
```

*The real source code of the function can be found [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/659067b99a84cf58ecc6e762e99cbc93bc4d1862/src/publickey.ts#L194)*

*As to what is a valid PDA, you can read more about it [here](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts) or [Rohan's answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2273/1065)*

#### TLDR:

A PDA is the address + the variation. I picture them like colors, a PDA is the address *AbCdEF* and bumps are colors (variations) of that address.

So referring to a PDA without the bump would be incomplete. For example, if you tell me:

- "the PDA is AbCd",
- I would ask you, "which AbCd, is that AbCd 255 (blue) or AbCd 252 (red)?

I guess that's the case you are in now, you are trying to initialize a PDA but you don't know what bump to use, if you do need a PDA then:

1. Solution 1: you need to know the bump in advance.
2. Solution 2: you don't know the bump. Then you need to "find back" that combination of pda + seed by running [findProgramAddress](https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#generate-a-pda). Meaning you need to know what are the seeds and the program address to feed to `findProgramAddress(seeds, programId)`;

Answer (score 3):

**Source reference for text + attached image:**
https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#generating-pdas

Highly recommend giving that website a look.

"To understand the concept behind PDAs, it may be helpful to consider that PDAs are not technically created, but rather found. PDAs are generated from a combination of seeds (such as the string “vote_account”) and a program id. This combination of seeds and program id is then run through a sha256 hash function to see whether or not they generate a public key that lies on the ed25519 elliptic curve.

In running our program id and seeds through a hash function, there is a ~50% chance that we actually end up with a valid public key that does lie on the elliptic curve. In this case, we simply add something to fudge our input a little bit and try again. The technical term for this fudge factor is a bump. In Solana, we start with bump = 255 and simply iterate down through bump = 254, bump = 253, etc. until we get an address that is not on the elliptic curve. This may seem rudimentary, but once found it gives us a deterministic way of deriving the same PDA over and over again."

[image: PDA]

Comment: These are both great answers - one high level with a wide audience, the other one more specific and cryptog focused. I chose the other one as it may appeal to more people but upvoted this too - thanks for the solid explanation!